# Mongoose create vs. new/save

Tags: mongoose

I have a Food schema with a required field `name`. For some reason, when I try to create a food item with the `create` function (below), it throws a `ValidationError: Path 'name' is required`, even though my object does indeed have a name field:

```
Food.create({
    name: "milk",
    daysUntilExpiration: 5
});
```

My mongoose debug output also shows that it's performing an insert, and the object being saved has the name field:

```
Mongoose: foods.insert({ name: 'milk', daysUntilExpiration: 5, _id: ObjectId("59608100cb0578165dd35de9"), __v: 0 })
```

On the other hand, if I create a new object and then save, it works as expected:

```
f = new Food({ name: "milk", daysUntilExpiration: 5 });
f.save() // no validation error!
```

Why is this behavior different? I was under the impression that the difference between create and new/save was purely for programming convenience ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305987/nodejs-mongoose-which-approach-is-preferable-to-create-a-document) wanting to work with an object after you create it but before you save to the DB), but it seems like I'm mistaken.

**EDIT: Stack trace of the validation error:**

```
ValidationError: Food validation failed: name: Path `name` is required.
        at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:63:24)
        at formatValue (util.js:352:36)
        at inspect (util.js:186:10)
        at exports.format (util.js:72:24)
        at Console.log (console.js:43:37)
        at tryCatcher (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:507:31)
        at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:581:18)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:697:14)
        at Async._drainQueue (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
        at Async._drainQueues (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
        at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
        at runCallback (timers.js:651:20)
        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:624:5)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:596:5) 

errors:
    { name:
      { MongooseError: Path `name` is required.
          at ValidatorError (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:24:11)
          at validate (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:744:13)
          at /Users/jess/herb/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:790:11
          at Array.forEach (native)
          at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/jess/herb/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:750:19)
          at /Users/jess/herb/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1462:9
          at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
        message: 'Path `name` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'name',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined } },
  _message: 'Food validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

**EDIT 2: Food schema:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 100
    },

    daysUntilExpiration: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Food', schema);
```

Comment: How can it _both_ throw an error _and_ insert a document?

Comment: @robertklep Exactly what I'm wondering!

Comment: A plausible explanation for that though: Mongoose logging might happen before the insert actually succeeds.

Comment: it's Mongoose that performs the validation, not MongoDB itself, so Mongoose would throw the error before even considering inserting something. I think the error is actually thrown somewhere else. The stack trace that accompanies it may provide some clues.

Comment: Can you also include your schema and any other pre save hooks/ validations you have defined ?

Comment: @Jess _"FoodItem validation failed"_. That sounds like a different model? The stack trace itself doesn't provide a clue what the root location of the error is, sadly.

Comment: Oops, I pasted a old chunk of output. I renamed the model since then, still the same error.

Comment: @TalhaAwan edited with schema, it's almost stupidly simple -- I don't have any other pre save hooks/validations of my own.

Comment: @Jess `create` working with me without error. Can't see what the problem is. Do you have FoodItem schema as well?

Comment: No, i renamed FoodItem to Food. I feel like create should generally work, too, but I'm not sure why this specific instance fails...

Comment: @Jess it's not re-createable (either by Talha or by me), so it must be something in your app that's causing it. Are you using Mongoose plugins?